# Bash file who ask user before deleting

Tags: bash, terminal, user-input, php-ziparchive

i am new to Linux Bash files, so maybe somebody can help me out here.
I want a Bash file which can archive files after x days (thats not the problem)

```
read days

find -mtime $days -exec zip packed.zip '{}' + && mv packed.zip /
```

But it also has to ask the user if it should store it there and delete the file afterwards.
So I need a loop, but I can't figure out how to get the Number of Files which are older than x days.
if I use `files=find -mtime$days`

with
`for $files > 0`  i get an error

if i use `for -f in find.....` i get the same
so my Question
can somebody tell me how to get the number of Files which are older than Input-Days

and maybe how to make it possible that every file get extra to the zip file after the user was asked and get deleted afterwards

Comment: What about `rm -i`?

Answer (score -2):

first, -mtime only works for me with if I pre-pone a plus-sign. So your loop is:

```
for i in $(find . -mtime +$days); do echo "what do we do with file $i"; read answer; done
```

"find . -mtime +$days" outputs a list of files. The $() around it hands it over to "for i" which iterates over it line-by-line. $i will first be the first line, then the second line, and so on. I describe this in http://linuxintro.org/wiki/BaBE_-_Bash_By_Examples#for_loops

Comment: The `for i in $(find ...); do ... done` approach is fatally flawed. What happens if a filename contains whitespace or glob character?

Comment: @M.NejatAydin: good point, you need to enclose $i into quotation marks.

Comment: It won't help for this case. That approach is utterly flawed beyond any hope of repair. Please read [for f in $(ls *.mp3)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: your link says "If you don't need recursion, you can use a simple glob" which is what I propose. Just quotes around the $i are needed and there must be an exception if there is no file older than $days. And you must consider that it's actually not days, but $days*24 hours.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) reports several flaws in the code, including the fatal one ([SC2044 - For loops over find output are fragile](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2044)) already identified by @M.NejatAydin .

Comment: Thanks for repling to my Question it works so far :))

i hope i can figure out the rest